# $\square\square\times\square =\square\square\square =\square\times\square\square\,\,\,$ fill blanks with distinct numbers from$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Fill in the blanks of:

> $$\square \;\square \times \square = \square \; \square \;\square =\square \times \square \;\square $$

With distinct numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

I was able to do it by trial-and-error, but I am looking for a more mathematical approach.

Comment: I don't see how this is linear algebra ...

Comment: ok recreational mathematics .i didnt noe which tag to put

Comment: Trial-and-error can be a very powerful "mathematical approach"!

Comment: You have 9 numbers: call them $x_{1},x_{2},\dots,x_{9}$. The equations you can set up would be the following:
$$(10x_{1}+x_{2})x_{3} =100x_{4}+10x_{5}+x_{6} =x_{7}(10x_{8}+x_{9})$$. The constraints are that $x_{j}\in \{1,2,\dots,9\},$ and $x_{i}\not=x_{j}$ for $i\not=j$.
Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Sometimes, trial-and-error is the only mathematical approach and sometimes the best!

Comment: The only thing slightly more mathematical than "trial and error" here is process of elimination.  We know, for example, that $5$ cannot appear in any of the number's $1$'s digit.

Comment: Well you can at least say that $x_1x_3 \ge 10$ and $x_7x_8\ge 10$

Comment: Note that neither the third nor the seventh digit can be $1$, since that could not produce a three-digit product.

Comment: Observe there is more than one way of doing it, consider swapping the first blank with the second to last, the second blank with the last blank, and the third blank with the third to last blank.

Comment: The 1 has to appear in the three-digit number, since as a one-digit it could not multiply to a three-digit, and as the second digit then $n\times(10+m)$ would be less than 200.

Comment: Another thing is that the x1, x2x3 , x7 , x8x9 are factors of x4x5x6

Comment: @StefanH.: Why couldn't $1$ appear in the units place of a two-digit number?

Comment: @dfeuer: If 1 were a first digit in a two-digit, then $n\times(10m+1)$ would give $n$ as the first digit, so $n$ would appear twice. If 1 were one of the one-digit numbers, then $1\times(10n+m)$ would be less than 100. If 1 were a second digit, then $n\times(10+m)$ would be less than 163. If 1

Comment: *vertical space* I can't edit my comment since the edit link is covered by one of the *Related* questions. lol

Comment: @xavierm02 Why is that the case?

Comment: Note that $n\times(10+m)$ is at most 162. $n\times(10m+1)$ would lead to $n$ appearing twice. And $1\times(10n+m) would be less than 100.

Comment: @ZettaSuro : Because the number in the middle is $\ge 100$.

Comment: @xavierm02 What if there's a carry from the first multiplication that brings the middle $\ge100$? E.g. $14\times9$.

Comment: There are four solutions. I doubt that the search tree can be placed on one math.stackexchange page.

Comment: @ZettaSure : Yeah right. For some reason I thought that because they were digits, that wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All right: This is "mathematical". In other words, some reasoning, with a lot of case checking. So, we have that: $$ab\cdot c = de\cdot f = ghi$$

- $b,c,f,e,i$ are not 5. Else requires a zero, or another 5.
- If $ghi$ is odd, then we can see that $b,c,e,f$, and $i$ all have to be odd. This is impossible if none of them are a $5$. Therefore, $ghi$ is even.
- $a$ and $d$ are not a $1$. Else, $g$ would also have be a $1$. We can also see that $c$ and $f$ are not $1$. $b$ and $e$ are not $1$ either. If $b$ was $1$, then $i = c$.
- Thus, either $g$ or $h$ is a $1$.

Now, look at the number $5$. It is either $a,d$, $g$ or $h$.

- First, assume that it is $g$. Then $ghi =51i$. And we can see that this is impossible.
- Next, assume it is $h$. then $ghi = 15i$. $i$ is even. So where is the $9$? $9$ cannot be either $a$ or $d$. So assume it is $b$.

Then we have $a9\cdot c = de\cdot f = 15i$. Since $c$ is odd, $a$ cannot be $2$. If $a =3, c=4$. We have:

$$39\cdot 4 = 156 = 78\cdot 2$$

So if $5= h$, one answer.

Otherwise, $5$ is either $a$ or $d$. Without loss of generality, assume it is $a$, so that
$5b\cdot c = de\cdot f = ghi$

Two cases, if $c$ is odd, $50\cdot c = 250$. We know that $g$ or $h$ is $1$. If $h$ is one, $b*c = 60$ something. That is impossible (only $7*9$ = 60 something, and that is odd).

So if $c$ is odd, $g = 1$. $c$ is then obviously $3$.

So we have $5b \cdot 3 = 1hi = de\cdot f$. b cannot be 2. Else, h is 5. If b is 4, we have 54*3 = 162 = ... impossible, as 7, 8, and 9 are left over.

As for $b =6$, we have $56\cdot 3 = 168$. Not possible. 2 instances of 6.

If b is 8. We have $58\cdot 3 = 174 = 29\cdot 6$

Final situation: if c is even.

$5b \cdot c = de \cdot f = ghi$

if $c$ is 2, then $g$ is 1, and $h$ is either 1 or 0. Impossible.

If $c$ is 4 or more, $g$ is not 1, so $h$ is 1.

We have

\begin{align}
5b \cdot c = g1i = de \cdot f
\end{align}

If $c$ is 4, $b = 3$. Then $53 \cdot 4 = 212$. Impossible.

If $c$ is 6, $g$ is 3. So b is 2. $52 \cdot 6 = 312$. Impossible.

If $c$ is 8, $g$ is 4. b is 2. $52 \cdot 8=416$. No even numbers left. Therefore, impossible.

Basically, that leaves the two answers.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer.

Comment: it would be great if you could finish the edit :)

Comment: Merr, all right.

Comment: @user86828 Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A number of observations can be made that narrow down the number of "guesses" that need to be made:

- Neither $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_7$ nor $x_8$ can be a $5$, because this would result in either a $0$ or another $5$ in the evaluation of the product. For the same reason, $x_6$ (the final digit of the product) cannot be $5$.
- Neither $(x_2,x_3)$ nor $(x_7,x_9)$ can be a pair of numbers such that the ones place of their product is one of the multipiers. That is, given a pair of numbers $m$ and $n$, $m\not\equiv mn \pmod{10}$ and $n\not\equiv\pmod{10}$.
- Neither $x_3$ nor $x_7$ can be a $1$, which would result in a $2$ digit product (and a repeat of each digit in the corresponding multiplier).
- You probably want the product to be a multiple of $6.$  It is not guaranteed, but gives more flexibility.
- The only digit pair that multiplies to $1$ is $3\times 7$, so the three-digit number cannot end in $1$. Similarly $3\equiv 7\times 9$ only, $7\equiv 3\times 9$ only, and $9$ is not the product of distinct digits. So the result is even.

Comment: More than just $x_3$ and $x_7$; a $5$, if it occurs, can only occur in $x_1$, $x_4$, $x_5$, or $x_8$; $5$ in any last digit is forbidden.  Similarly, $x_2$ and $x_9$ can't be $1$s, either.  Further, we know that $x_6$ must be even - if it were odd then all five of the last digits would be odd, and since there are only four odd numbers to go around (remember, we're not allowed to use $5$ there) then the product must be even.

Answer (score 2):

For general reference, a brute force approach leads to there only being two distinct solutions:
$$29 \cdot 6 = 174 = 58 \cdot 3$$
$$39 \cdot 4 = 156 = 78 \cdot 2$$

**Edit:**
If you want to see this for yourself:

```
import itertools
l = itertools.permutations(range(1,10))
for x in l:
    a, b, c = (10*x[0] + x[1]) * x[2], 100*x[3] + 10*x[4]+ x[5], (10*x[6] + x[7])*x[8]
    if (a == b and b == c): 
        print 10*x[0] + x[1], "*", x[2], "=", b, "=", 10*x[6] + x[7], "*", x[8]
```

Comment: How do we know that these are the only two?

Comment: @ZettaSuro - brute force.

Comment: Of course it can be done by programming , But the question is mathematical approach

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam - I know, but I thought the actual solutions may be useful, both for the OP and also for inspiration as to a "mathematical solution", assuming such a one exists.

Comment: I really doubt what inspiration it gains . The person @Maths lover has told that he got the solution by trial and error. So solution is not the problem but how we can get it is the problem

Comment: I hope this answer can be a comment . The owner @Maths lover should remove this from it being an accepted answer .

Comment: Well, at the very least it corroborates Ross Milikan's observation that it would be a good idea to have the product divisible by $6$.

Comment: Useful to check.

Answer (score 1):

Elimination, elimination.
$$\overline{x_1x_2} \cdot x_3 = \overline{x_4x_5x_6}= x_7 \cdot \overline{x_8x_9}$$
Let's call :
$$\overline{x_1x_2} = a$$
$$\overline{x_4x_5x_6} = b$$
$$\overline{x_8x_9} = c$$
So
$$a \cdot x_3 = b = x_7 \cdot c $$

- What we know:

  1. $x_3$ or $x_7$ cant't be $1$
  2. $a$ or $x_3$ can't be both primes. Also $c$ and $x_7$.
  3. $b$ cant't be prime
  4. $ 123\le c\le 776 = 98 *7 $
  5. Last digit of $a$ or $c$ can't be $1$ because $\color{red}{x_3} \cdot \overline{x_1 1} = \overline{x_4x_5 \color{red}{x_3}}$
  6. The last digit of a,b or c can't be $5$

     This narows c to 500 numbers. If i have more ideas i will post here.